# C++ std::stoul not throwing exception

Tags: c++, string-conversion

I have a function to check if a string is a valid `unsigned int`:

```
unsigned long int getNum(std::string s, int base)
{
    unsigned int n;
    try
    {
        n = std::stoul(s, nullptr, base);
        std::cout << errno << '\n';
        if (errno != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR" << '\n';
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Value is too big");
    }
    return n;
}
```

However when I enter a value such as `0xfffffffff` (9 f's), `errno` is still 0 (and no exception is thrown). Why is this the case?

Comment: Maybe because your `sizeof(unsigned long)` is 8, because you're using a 64 bit platform?

Comment: All we can do is make educated guesses, but Sam very likely correct. [According to reliable documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul), `stoul` returns an `unsigned long`. [The size of a `long` is greater than or equal to the size of an `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). Looks like you'll have to perform the size test yourself if you want to be sure. That said, you generally don't want to use an exception to catch a mistake like this because humans are dumb and punch in the wrong numbers all the time.

Comment: Also note that, if an exception is thrown by `stoul` (you can try with your input and `stoi`), the errno part of your function is never reached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see what happens when you assign `0xfffffffff` (9 f's) to an `unsigned int` on an 64-bit machine.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    unsigned int n = 0xfffffffff; //decimal value 68719476735
    std::cout << n << '\n';

}
```

The implicit conversion will result in a warning by the compiler but will not cause an exception.

The result type of `stoul` is `unsigned long` which on 64-bit machine is big enough to hold  `0xfffffffff`, so there will be no exception.

Comment: No. `std::stoul` throws an exception if the value cannot be represented in the target type. Normal conversions between integer values (as in the example in this answer) have nothing to do with the behavior of `std::stoul`.

Comment: The two exceptions are `std::invalid_argument` if no conversion could be performed,  
`std::out_of_range` if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type or if the underlying function (std::strtoul or std::strtoull) sets errno to ERANGE.  But the result type of `stoul` is `unsigned long` which on a 64-bit machine can hold upto 18446744073709551615.

Comment: Your comment is correct. It still has nothing to do with your answer. The fact that the **integer value** `0xfffffffff` can be implicitly converted (with truncation on some platforms) to `unsigned int` has nothing to do with the specification of how the function `std::stoul` treats **character sequences**.

Comment: The question was about why there is no exception. In this case, which criteria for exception is met?

Comment: Yes, the question is about why there is no exception. And the answer is, because the **text** `"0xfffffffff"`can be converted to `unsigned long` without overflowing. Your answer talks about converting the **integer constant** `0xfffffffff` to `unsigned int`, a completely different matter.

Comment: I was under the impression that the asker posted this question because he thought the implicit conversion of `unsigned long` to `unsigned int` should produce an exception. So I gave an example to show that it only results in a warning and not an exception.

Comment: Anyway, I will update the answer shortly to remove the confusion.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're getting at. I've removed my downvote. Still, the use of `errmo` indicates that the question is about the function call, since `errno` is only changed by explicitly setting it. It's used by the standard library to indicate that something went wrong.